# jekyll doesn't render latex exported from org-mode as html

Tags: export, latex, jekyll, org-mode, mathjax

I would like to ask a question regarding thhe integration of jekyll and org-mode, specifically when it comes to creating blog posts that contain latex and math formulas.

The problem:
Jekyll seems not to render properlly the latex code because whenever I visit my blog post It shows as not rendered.

Take a look at the picture below to understand what is being rendered on the webpage.

[latex not rendered properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNZXR.png)

This is what I have written in my .org file.

[latex as it was written in the .org file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N6vl.png)

This is the configuaration used in .org-mode to export to html

```
(require 'ox-publish)
(require 'ox-html)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
    '(("org-posts"
     ;; Path to your org files.
     :base-directory "~/path/to/org/files/"
     :base-extension "org"
     ;; Path to your Jekyll project.
     :publishing-directory "~/path/to/blog/root/dir/"
     :recursive t
     :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
     :headline-levels 4
     :html-extension "html"
     :body-only t
     :table-of-contents nil
     :html-mathjax "path \"https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js\""
    )

    ("org-imgs"
     :base-directory "~/path/to/org/files"
     ;:base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|php"
     :base-extension "jpg\\|gif\\|png\\|jpeg"
     :publishing-directory "~/path/to/blog/assets/images/"
     :recursive t
     :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
     :table-of-contents nil
     :html-mathjax "path \"https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js\""
     )

    ("blog" :components ("org-posts" "org-imgs"))))
```

This is what I have putted in my `~/path/to/blog/_includes/head.html` regarding the mathjax engine.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
        processEscapes: true
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
    </head>
<body>
```

What am I doing worng? I've been banging my head all day around this and still haven't found any solution. I've tried most of the things I've found on the internet but nothing seems to work.

I've also tried to include all the jsMath folder which has the rendering engine for parsing latex, in the blog root directory and in the head.html I pointed to fetch the javascript engine from the jsMath folder but unfortunately no luck, again.

Please advice how to proceed in solving this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? Do you have a live sample page perhaps?

Comment: Yes, this is a [sample](https://kirk86.github.io/2016/03/fundamental-theorem-algebra/)

Comment: That link will trigger mixed-content blocking. If you load the page over http it works as expected. Try loading MathJax over https.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger thank you that solved the problem!

Comment: Glad to hear that's all.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.